# Using two Transformers with ml pyspark in a pipline

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, probability

I created two tranformers with pyspark the first one calculate a propability and the other one calculate in different way another probability and each one of them create a new column and they use different dataframe.
I want to know how to deal with that and put it in a pipline. I was thing to put the output df of the first transformer as an input df othe second transformer but i d'ont know if it's possible:
here is my first transformer :

```
class ProbabilityEstimator(Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol):

def __init__(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
    super(ProbabilityEstimator, self).__init__()
    self._setDefault(inputCol=inputCol, outputCol=outputCol)  
    self.setParams(inputCol=inputCol, outputCol=outputCol)  

def setParams(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
    return self._set(inputCol=inputCol, outputCol=outputCol)  

def _transform(self, softbins_df):
    prior_window = Window.partitionBy('softbin_first_test').orderBy(F.col('time_window')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    prior_pass_prob = F.sum('total_pass').over(prior_window) / F.sum(F.col('total_pass') + F.col('total_fail')).over(prior_window)
    prior_fail_prob = F.sum('total_fail').over(prior_window) / F.sum(F.col('total_pass') + F.col('total_fail')).over(prior_window)

    rho = 0.3
    alpha = prior_pass_prob * (1 - rho) / rho
    beta = prior_fail_prob * (1 - rho) / rho
    pass_prob = alpha / (alpha + beta)

    return softbins_df.withColumn(self.getOutputCol(), pass_prob)
```

and Thid is the second one :

```
class ContactSiteEstimator(Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol):

def __init__(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
    super(ContactSiteEstimator, self).__init__()
    self._setDefault(inputCol=inputCol, outputCol=outputCol)  
    self.setParams(inputCol=inputCol, outputCol=outputCol)  

def setParams(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
    return self._set(inputCol=inputCol, outputCol=outputCol)  

def _transform(self, merged_df):
    # Calculate the number of fails per site_number over the short_window
    fails_per_window_df = merged_df.loc[merged_df['bincode_type_last_retest'] == 'FAIL'].groupby(['tester_first_test', 'site_nbr_first_test', 'short_window']).size().reset_index(name='fails_in_site')
    total_fails = fails_per_window_df.groupby(['tester_first_test', 'short_window'])['fails_in_site'].sum().reset_index(name = 'total_fails')
    # Merge
    df = pd.merge(merged_df, fails_per_window_df, on=['short_window', 'tester_first_test', 'site_nbr_first_test'])
    df = pd.merge(df, total_fails, on=['short_window', 'tester_first_test'])
    # Calculate the probability for the contact site imbalance for each row
    df['contact_site_imbalance_probability'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['fails_in_site'] / row['total_fails']) , axis=1)

    # Fill missing values with 0 
    df['contact_site_imbalance_probability'].fillna(0, inplace=True)


    return df['contact_site_imbalance_probability']
```

Any ideas ?